# How to compare two CSV files by column and save the differences in csv file using pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I have two csv files like the following

File1

```
x1 10.00 a1
x2 10.00 a2
x3 11.00 a1
x4 10.50 a2
x5 10.00 a3
x6 12.00 a3
```

File2

```
x1
x4
x5
```

I would like to create a new file that contains

```
x2
x3
x6
```

using pandas or python

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with `~` for filtering of values not existing in `df1[0]` - in first column with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
import pandas as pd

#create DataFrame from first file
df1 = pd.read_csv(file1, sep=";", header=None)
print (df1)
    0     1   2
0  x1  10.0  a1
1  x2  10.0  a2
2  x3  11.0  a1
3  x4  10.5  a2
4  x5  10.0  a3
5  x6  12.0  a3

#create DataFrame from second file
df2 = pd.read_csv(file2, header=None, sep='|')
print (df2)
    0
0  x1
1  x4
2  x5

s = df1.loc[~df1[0].isin(df2[0]), 0]
print (s)
1    x2
2    x3
5    x6
Name: 0, dtype: object

#write to file
s.to_csv('new.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: Do I have to import something i python?

Comment: I get an error on tokenizing data C error expected 1 field saw 2

Comment: I do import pandas as pd 

df1 = pd.read_csv('SKUS.csv', sep="\s+", header=None)
df2 = pd.read_csv('retails_csv', header=None)
s = df1.loc[~df1[0].isin(df2[0]), 0]
s.to_csv('update.csv', index=False)

Comment: @Nikos - in first file is separator tab or space or comma?

Comment: a semicolumn ; character

Comment: @Nikos - so need `df1 = pd.read_csv(file1, sep=";", header=None)`

Comment: @Nikos - Also there is no csv header?

Comment: Now I get FutureWarning the signature of series.to_csv was aligned to that of Dataframe header will change its default value from false to true pass an explicit value to suppress this warning

Comment: There no headers

Comment: @Nikos - Last use `s.to_csv('new.csv', index=False, header=False)`

Comment: The initial csv has 420 rows the second csv 203 rows why the results are 420 again and not 217?

Comment: @Nikos - is second file is ony one column? Or multiple with separator?

Comment: The SKU.csv has one column the other retails_csv.csv has 6 columns

Comment: @Nikos - if separator is also `;` use `df2 = pd.read_csv(file2, header=None, sep=';')`

Comment: I think I had them opposite I swap them but again I got error tokenizing data C erro expected 1 saw 2

Comment: @Nikos - What is separator in `file2` ?

Comment: There isnt a separator only file 1 has

Comment: @Nikos - Are data confidental?

Comment: @Nikos - Is possible send me your files to my email from my profile?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190969/discussion-between-nikos-and-jezrael).